# Permission denied for ProcessBuilder and FFMPEG in MAC

Tags: java, ffmpeg, process, exec, processbuilder

I tried to run `ProcessBuilder` command in Mac. I couldn't run because of permission issues. Also, I tried to copy the folder and kept in the local folder. I even tried to do `chmod`. It's not working. I tried to execute the following code for frame capture using FFmPeg.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
    "/Users/balaji/Documents", "-i",
    "Documents/Theintouchables.mp4", "-f", "image2",
    "Documents" + "/" + "Test_Image" + "_%07d.jpg");
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = builder.start();
```

Comment: 1) See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and (continue to) use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. 2) *"It's not working."* Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Comment: If I had to guess based on the code, I would say that the documents folder isn’t an executable file.